# I cannot access my WP website after changing settings

Tags: wp-admin

I have broken my website. I went into the general settings in the Dashboard and changed my site URL from `www.therealdeal.org.uk/newsite` to `www.therealdeal.org.uk`. I left the Home address as `www.therealdeal.org.uk/newsite`. I now get:

> This website is temporarily unavailable.

I have accessed PHPmyadmin and manually changed the wp-options table but it does not seem to have any effect. I cannot access my website or Admin panel any more.

Comment: Have you also changed your `wp-config.php` settings?

Comment: Just went to your site. Looks like you got it fixed...

Answer (score 0):

**To get your site back**

Open wp-config.php - ( add these lines )

```
define('WP_HOME','www.therealdeal.org.uk/newsite');
define('WP_SITEURL','www.therealdeal.org.uk/newsite');
```

or to have it autmatically map to the right places

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
```

Load the admin or login pages a few times